# How to get "v.3.1.2" in string by regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need get "v3.4.2" in string by regex php.
String: "ABCDEF v3.4.2 GHI KLMN";

Comment: it is fixed value or variant

Comment: it is variant @SantoshRamKunjir

Comment: starts with v and length is fixed?

Comment: length is variant. example: v1.0, v1.3.2.3, v3.4.3.2.3

Comment: @user3912569 A fairly easy task. What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

**A safe RegEx to work with variable lengths and digits:**

```
\bv(\d+\.)+\d+\b
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oH6hV4/1)</kbd>

How it works:

```
\b          # Word Boundary
v           # v
(\d+\.)     # Digit(s) followed by . - i.e. 3. or 4.
+           # Match many digit(s) followed by dot - i.e. 3.4.2. or 5.6.
\d+         # Final digit of version (not included above because it has no trailing .)
\b          # Word Boundary
```

---

If the format is exactly as shown, use this shorter RegEx:

```
\bv\d\.\d\.\d\b
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kR4bW3/1)</kbd>

`\b` marks a word boundary, so it will not capture inside `donotv3.4.2capturethis`

How it works:

```
\b             # Word Boundary
v              # v
\d\.\d\.\d     # 3.4.2
\b             # Word Boundary
```

Comment: First of all it's not matching variable length. Second it will leave trialing dot and will match everything else in `v3.4.2.`

Comment: @noob Fair point. But that trailing dot could be a full stop, e.g. `We released a new version of our product, v3.4.2. It is very good and has .....`. And how does it not match a variable length? It will match `v33.44.22` and `v3.4.2.3.4.2`?

Comment: [This is how it's not matching variable length.](https://regex101.com/r/kR4bW3/2) P.S: I see this was your initial regex. You seem to have edited you answer 18 minutes ago.

Comment: @noob **You used the wrong RegEx!** Use the top one, the one I explicitly stated as to match variable length! [**New Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kR4bW3/3)

Comment: @Biffen: I did read the initial one which was wrong. And also the **Edited one 20 minutes ago**.

Comment: @noob You wrote your comment about it not match variable length 8 mins ago. This is 13 mins **after** I edited it

Comment: Good luck with upvotes and points. Am out of here.

Comment: `:D` Thanks, see you later!